# MonoTouch event handler in ViewDidLoad not working sometimes?

Tags: ipad, events, xamarin.ios

There are several ways to handle event in MonoTouch. It looks to me that mapping the event in IB is the most reliable way to do. What I don't understand is why sometimes the event mapped in ViewDidLoad doesn't work. For example, I have a UITextField (called tfCode). If it's mapped in IB for EditingDidEnd to tfCodeChanged, it works:

```
partial void tfCodeChanged(NSObject sender)
{
    ...
}
```

However, in ViewDidLoad, if I put in the following code, it doesn't get hit:

```
tfCode.EditingDidEnd += delegate {
    ...
};
```

But in general I'm doing a lot of event handling in ViewDidLoad and they mostly work.

So, I'm confused. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: It's difficult to see why (and harder to explain) without seeing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The events are triggered as long as you do not override the internal handlers by assigning to either the Delegate or WeakDelegate properties.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer a little bit more? In this case, I initially only have mapped the outlet, no actions. The event attached to the outlet in ViewDidLoad didn't get triggered. However, then, when I mapped the action in IB, I got the event. Are you telling me that the first case should have worked?